# AngularJS - child component not updating parent component data

Tags: angularjs, components

I'm writing an app with AngularJS 1.5.3

I have a parent component with some data in it that needs to be updated in the child component. Right now the data is not updating in the parent component even though the input boxes on the child look like they are updating.

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aubz88/ab85L19c/

Here is some sample code:

```
var grandChildComponent = {
  bindings: {
    min: '<',
    max: '<'
  },
    template: `
    <div>
      Grand Child component
      <input ng-model="$ctrl.min" />
      <input ng-model="$ctrl.max" />
    </div>
  `
};
```

Comment: You should use **two-way data bindings (=)** in both of your child and grand child components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because you are using one-way bindings ([Reference docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) and a [helpful article here](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/angularjs-component-binding-types-my-experiences-10f354d4660)).

If you want your data updates to go from-parent-to-child and from-child-to-parent, then you need two-way data binding using the symbol `=`.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/chbfoa9t/1/)

E.g.

```
var grandChildComponent = {
    bindings: {
        min: '=',
        max: '='
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            Grand Child component
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.min" />
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.max" />
        </div>
    `
};
```